# Advertisement 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: support, advertising, error-message

Looking for an answer to a problem and stumbled across this:

[image]

Below is the source of the advert:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="250" width="300" src="https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjsi/ad.atdmt.com/71183/12853070/d/a.html;p=11087211335483;cod=1;idfa=;aaid=;idfa_lat=;aaid_lat=;cache=1490776894681?click=http%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3DAqs8WxjKs4IYtxaIJL-xkeNZECI%26url=" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="1"></iframe>
```

Not sure if it'll help but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173941/error-catalina-home-variable-is-not-define-correctly-in-this-environment) is the link to the question that had the error:

I still have the page open so if you need more details I can give you them just tell me what you want / to do :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not coming from us directly. The ads we show aren't served through nginx. It's probably just a display ad, whose serving server had an issue. These things happen from time to time and I don't think it's something to worry about.

If you reload and the problem persists then it might become interesting. But I couldn't manage to repro on my side.

Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Ah, adsafeprotected strikes again.